# Hot to encrypt using PHP and decrypt with Outlook Express

Tags: php, email, outlook, public-key-encryption

I'm trying to create this kind of system:

- a user writes a mail with confidential data in it
- I manage them with PHP, sending them to the administrator
- only administrator should be able to open that mail

Achieving this seems to be possible this way:

- encrypt the mail using an Outlook Express-compatible encryption (DES, 3DES, RC" (various bit)) with PHP and an asymmetric pubblic key.
- decrypt the mail using Outlook Express with an account that owns the asymmetric private key

However, I totally don't know what kind of certificate should I use, how to get it (I'd like to get at least a free one to do some testing) and I'm not sure this infrastructure would work.

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187738/what-is-the-best-way-to-send-a-secure-email-in-php/3187818#3187818

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PGP for this. It's more or less the standard of encrypting mails and there is a free open source utility for the server side of things. In the client, your users will have to install a plugin of which there are several to pick from.

I don't know of any native bindings of GnuPG for php, but you can execute it over the command line, using `shell_exec`

Update: Looks like someone even wrote a tutorial on this: http://devzone.zend.com/article/1265

Comment: I've been searching informations about this GnuPG, but I'm pretty sure there is no way I can use it, because I don't own the server I'm hosting the service to, so I'm not allowed to install anything. I need something native for PHP